# Is there a generic method to retrieve entity IDs?

Tags: 8, entities

I have seen this code suggesting how to return a list of entity IDs:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('type', $bundle);
$entity_ids = $query->execute();
```

but this requires the knowledge of when to use "type" or what "type" is. For example, for user entity i would think setting type to $bundle = 'user' would work - but it gives error.

for terms from a vocab i would expect type to be set to the name of the vocab; but that also gives an error.

Is there a generic method to call for entity_type that would hint at what is required to do a query for entity ids?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the bundle key, which can be obtained from the entity type:

```
$entity_type = 'node';

// Load the entity type definition and get its keys.
$keys = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getDefinition($entity_type)
  ->getKeys();

$query = \Drupal::entityQuery($entity_type);

// 'bundle' is optional, if not provided it will be the same as the entity type ID, 
// but obviously you won't need to use it as a condition.
if (mb_strlen($keys['bundle'])) {
  $query->condition($keys['bundle'], $bundle);  
}

$entity_ids = $query->execute();
```

See [`EntityType::getKeys()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityType.php/function/EntityType%3A%3AgetKeys/8.6.x) for more information.